# Catchable fatal error using PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am trying to create an email confirmation when registering in a page. and i am receiving this error when submiting it.

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class PHPMailer could not be converted to string in C:\wamp\www\includes\reg.php on line 90
```

and here is my code,

```
<?php

session_start();
require '../class.phpmailer.php';


$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Mailer = 'smtp';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com'; // "ssl://smtp.gmail.com" didn't worked
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';

$email = $_POST['email'];

$mail->Username = "XXX@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "XXX";

$mail->IsHTML(true); // if you are going to send HTML formatted emails
$mail->SingleTo = true; // if you want to send a same email to multiple users. multiple emails will be sent one-by-one.

$mail->From = "XXX@gmail.com";
$mail->FromName = "Your Name";

$mail->addAddress("XXX@live.com","User 1");
$mail->addAddress($email,"User 2");

$mail->addCC("user.3@ymail.com","User 3");
$mail->addBCC("user.4@in.com","User 4");

$mail->Subject = "Confirm your Account!!";
$mail->Body = "Confirm Your Email, Click link to verify your account,,<br /><br />http://localhost/includes/emailconfirm.php?email=$_POST[email]&code=$mail";

if(!$mail->Send())
    echo "Message was not sent <br />PHPMailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
else
    echo "Message has been sent";


header('refresh: 0; url=../index.php#openModal');
$message = "You are now Registered, Please Sign In.";
echo("<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>");

}


?>
```

this one was the line getting the error,

```
$mail->Body = "Confirm Your Email, Click link to verify your account,,<br /><br />http://localhost/includes/emailconfirm.php?email=$_POST[email]&code=$mail";
```

and I dont know if using $email works, i need to send email to the email the user has submitted. please help thank you.

Comment: Don't use `ssl` on port 465; for gmail use `tls` on 587. Update your PHPMailer, and [read the docs](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki).

Comment: The answers given explain why you are getting that particular error, but it would be good to know what you're actually trying to achieve, since appending the `$mail` var to that URL makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `$mail->Body = "Confirm Your Email, Click link to verify your account,,<br /><br />http://localhost/includes/emailconfirm.php?email=$_POST[email]&code=$mail";`

try using `$message = "Confirm Your Email, Click link to verify your account,,<br /><br />http://localhost/includes/emailconfirm.php?email=$_POST[email]&code=$mail";`

then $mail->Body = $message;

Comment: even though the answer is already accepted.. can you please elaborate why this would make a difference? I have the understanding that the class doesn't provide a `__toString()` magic method, and storing the string in a temporary zval before assigning it to the objects property should not make a difference at all! Or does it? How?

Comment: It doesn't make a difference. Appending the `$mail` var either way makes no sense.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the end of the line with error where you have `&code=$mail";`. You previously defined `$mail` as `PHPMailer`, where probably this class doesn't provide `__toString()` function.

`__toString()` is a magic function which is called upon when the object has to be converted to string. In your situation, when `$mail` (a `PHPMailer` object) has to be inserted as a concatenation in a string, it tries to call `__toString()` but none is provided.